# I am having trouble sanitizing the User Input for a string

Tags: c#, sanitization

I am currently doing a basic RNG program but I ran into trouble when sanitizing. I am terrible at programming so I may be missing something, but I can't figure out how to make sure the user does not enter a string. My problem is in the very last if statement at the bottom of the code. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Here is the code:

```
    using System;

    namespace Lab_9
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                //Declaring range for RNG
                int minValue = 1;
                int maxValue = 10;

                //Creating RNG
                Random random = new Random();
                int number = random.Next(minValue, maxValue);

                //Getting user int
                Console.WriteLine("Please guess a number between 1-10");
                int UserInput = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                bool validInput = Sanitize(UserInput);

                //Checking if their number is greater than the RNG Number
                if (UserInput > number)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Your number is more than the generated number");
                }
                //Checking if it is smaller
                if (UserInput < number)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Your number is less than the generated number");
                }
                //Checking if they guessed the right number
                if (UserInput == number)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Congrats! You guessed the number!");
                }

                Console.WriteLine("The random number was " + number);
            }

            //Sanitizing their input
            private static bool Sanitize(int UserInput)
            {
                //Checks for invalid numbers
                if(UserInput > 10)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Please do not enter a number that is greater than 10");
                    return false;
                }

                if(UserInput < 1)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Please do not enter a number that is less than 1");
                    return false;
                }

                //Checking if they put chars instead of numbers
                if()
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Please do not enter a letter, only a number");
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Look into [Int.TryParse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=net-5.0) as the way you currently have it, if a user enters something other than a number, it will throw. TBH, I would make this check in the `Sanitize` routine and be done with it.

Comment: Thank you for the help!

Comment: You're welcome, if you still have questions about this, please update your post and someone would be glad to help you.

Answer (score 0):

there's some ways to do this

You can int.TryParse() or you could just use try catch.
If it's not an Int an Exception will be thrown

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Declaring range for RNG
            int minValue = 1;
            int maxValue = 10;

            //Creating RNG
            Random random = new Random();
            int number = random.Next(minValue, maxValue);

            //Getting user int
            Console.WriteLine("Please guess a number between 1-10");
            int UserInput = Sanitize(Console.ReadLine());

            if(UserInput == 0)
            {
                return;
            }
            //Checking if their number is greater than the RNG Number
            if (UserInput > number)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Your number is more than the generated number");
            }
            //Checking if it is smaller
            if (UserInput < number)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Your number is less than the generated number");
            }
            //Checking if they guessed the right number
            if (UserInput == number)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Congrats! You guessed the number!");
            }

            Console.WriteLine("The random number was " + number);

        }

        private static int Sanitize(object input)
        {
            int userInput = default;

            try
            {
                userInput = Convert.ToInt32(input);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //Checking if they put chars instead of numbers
                Console.WriteLine("Please do not enter a letter, only a number");
            }


            //Checks for invalid numbers
            if (userInput > 10)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please do not enter a number that is greater than 10");
            }

            if (userInput < 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please do not enter a number that is less than 1");
            }
            return userInput;
        }
```

Comment: I would definitely recommend `Int32.TryParse()` over a try catch. It is generally considered bad form to use exceptions for control flow.